# Swing Timer, how to pause and resume it?

Tags: java, swing, timer

i have a timer that counts the spent time and other calculations, but i need when i click on pause button the timer to pause, and then resume. How do i pause it?

Answer (score 8):

There is no pause & resume API for Timer. You will need to code for it.

Here is example which pauses and resumes Timer on mouseover.

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/Anappletthatcountsdownfromaspecifiedtime.htm

Hope this helps.