# How to make a variable run across classes

Tags: java, variables, netbeans

I am doing a swing project of a easy game. When the user clicks the "How to play" tab I make a jframe appear with the rules and the timer of the game stops (i coded the Jframe in a different class). How can i make the timer start again when the user closes the "how to play Jframe" (the timer starts when the boolean value it true)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Swing Timer, how to pause and resume it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3537484/swing-timer-how-to-pause-and-resume-it)

Comment: i have paused it but when they close the jframe i want it to start again

Answer (score 0):

If you create the "How to play"-JFrame in your main frame, then you can simply keep a private field there, containing the time elapsed (I'm assuming an int, containing number of seconds).
Then you can call a `startClock(0)` method on your first startup, and add a call to a `pauseClock()` (this should save current time to the `currentTime` field) method in the `ActionListener` of your "How to play"-button.
Then, to the "How to play"-JFrame, add a WindowListener (use an Adapter, so you don't need to implement all the methods). This should be done in code, in the mainframe:

```
howToFrame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){
    public void onWindowClosed(WindowEvent e){
        startClock(currentTime);
    }
});
```